# beautifulsoup href returns empty string

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im sure this is an easy one but somehow I ve been stuck to get the `href` link under the `a` tag that jumps to each of the product detail pages. I dont see any javascript wrapped around as well. What am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'https://undefeated.com/search?type=product&q=nike'
] 

 final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/python/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
        driver.get(url)
        products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-grid-item  ']")))]
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        time.sleep(1)
        href = soup.find_all['href']
        print(href)
```

output:
`[]`

I then tried `soup.find_all('a')` and it did spit out the a whole bunch including `href` I am looking for, but still cannot specifically extract only the href...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to find_all the `a` tag and then try to print the `href` attribute.

You requests.Session code should be like this:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(url)
        products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-grid-item  ']")))]
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        time.sleep(1)
        a_links = soup.find_all('a')
        for a in a_links:
            print(a.get('href'))
```

Then all the links will be printed.